# Concat 2 lists with the generic being a class, ignoring duplicated properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I use to store my data in a double string dictionary, I've now refactored my code to use a `DownloadFile` class where I can store more than a KeyValue pair.

So this,

```
Dictionary<string, string> downloads;
```

Becomes

```
List<DownloadFile> downloads;
```

I use to concat 2 dictionarys, skipping the duplicates like so.

```
imageUrls = imageUrls.Concat(newImages.Where(x => !imageUrls.ContainsKey(x.Key))).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

I need to do this with the new system, here is as far as I have got.

```
imageUrls = imageUrls.Concat(newImages).ToList();
```

I can't access properties inside the DownloadFile class, atleast I don't know how to. Can anybody advise me into a solution for this problem? I couldn't find anything from a google search.

Each class DownloadFile has a property called Address, I simply need to avoid adding duplicated instances of `DownloadFile` to the main list inside the new images list, ignoring duplicated `Address` properties.

Comment: `GroupBy()` Address, then select the `First()` of every group (arbitrarily ignoring the others in the group i.e the duplicates)

Comment: Thanks! Although, I couldn't understand just from your short comment. Could you include a code example in an answer with that information?

Comment: imageUrls.Concat(newImages).Distinct()....well - not quite with your data-structure.Update: however - you could do it if your Download class implemented...um...IComparable<DownloadFile>

Comment: Distinct() works on simple values, or if you're insterested in object identity. Here, carbin wants to avoid duplicates of a specific property. For Distinct() to work here, `DownloadFile` has to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or you have to implement your own custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from your question this could be solved by:

```
List<DownloadFile> newImages = new List<DownloadFile>();
        List<DownloadFile> downloads = new List<DownloadFile>();

        foreach (var item in newImages)
        {
            if(!downloads.Any(x => x.Address == item.Address))
                downloads.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use LINQ's Except method (with IEqualityComparer)

Ideally we'd like to use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx), which would make things very simple. It's very easy to use on primitive types. But for your `DownloadFile`, LINQ doesn't automatically know to check the `Address` to determine if one item is a duplicate of another. So we have to tell it, by writing a short class:

```
class DownloadFileComparer : IEqualityComparer<DownloadFile>
{
    public bool Equals(DownloadFile a, DownloadFile b)
    {
        return a.Address == b.Address;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DownloadFile f)
    {
        return f.Address.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now can pass that comparer class to the `Except` method, like this:

```
var list = new List<DownloadFile>
{
    new DownloadFile { Address = "http://old" },
    new DownloadFile { Address = "http://duplicate" }
};
var adds = new List<DownloadFile>
{
    new DownloadFile { Address = "http://new" },
    new DownloadFile { Address = "http://duplicate" }
};

list.AddRange(adds.Except(list, new DownloadFileComparer()));

foreach (var d in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Address);
}
```

Output:

```
http://old
http://duplicate
http://new
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cqLTcF)

### How to avoid writing a comparison class every time

Now maybe you think it's daft to have to write a class every time you come up with a type that needs equality comparison on one of its properties. I agree!  So you can write a generalized class and put it in your project somewhere-- here is what mine looks like:

```
static public class EqualityComparerExtensionMethods
{

    public class GeneralComparer<TItem> : IEqualityComparer<TItem> 
    {
        protected readonly Func<TItem,object> _propertyFunction;

        public GeneralComparer(Func<TItem,object> propertyFunction)
        {
            _propertyFunction = propertyFunction;
        }
        public bool Equals(TItem a, TItem b)
        {
            return _propertyFunction(a).Equals(_propertyFunction(b));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(TItem f)
        {
            return _propertyFunction(f).GetHashCode();
        }

    }

    static public GeneralComparer<TItem> GetEqualityComparer<TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> This, Func<TItem,object> propertyFunction)
    {
        return new GeneralComparer<TItem>(propertyFunction);
    }
}
```

And now all you need to do is this:

```
list.AddRange(adds.Except(list, list.GetEqualityComparer(f => f.Address)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a massive list and then filter it

```
var newList = listOne.Concat(listTwo)
             .GroupBy(x => x.Address)
             .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
             .ToList();
```

Or add first one list and then the other, if there are no duplicates within each list, only when you combine them

```
var newList = new List<DownloadFile>(listOne);
newList.AddRange(
          listTwo.Where(x => !listOne.Any(z => z.Address == x.Address));
```

If the list are huge (tens of thousands of entries++) you could also consider a custom equality comparer.

```
class DownloadFileAddressComparer : IEqualityComparer<DownloadFile>
{
    public bool Equals(DownloadFile x, DownloadFile y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x?.Address, y?.Address);       
    }
    public int GetHashCode(DownloadFile obj)
    {
        return obj.Address?.GetHashCode() ?? 0; // In case of null address
    }
}
/* ... */    
var newList = listOne.Concat(listTwo)
              .Distinct(new DownloadFileAddressComparer())
              .ToList();
```